# Monotouch: WCF is experimental?

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios

I would like to know if the WCF version for monotouch is stable or not. Do you have any info?

Thank in advance. Regards. L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's experimental, so not fully supported.

I have used it in a big application in the past though, and for the most part everything worked perfectly. You need to use the Silverlight proxy generator, but everything works ok. I found a few bugs along the way, and the MonoTouch team was just great in getting those fixed as soon as possible. This was almost a year ago, so my guess is that things are probably in a better shape now.

If you really need to so webservices (instead of simple http calls), I would suggest you give it a try, before disregarding it. You'll see that unless you need very very specific things, everything really works well.